# R in Python(rpy2) vs Rstudio mismatch of results

Tags: r, python-2.7, rpy2

I want to evaluate clustering results in python using CDbw metric that is in R package fpc. I am testing the CDbw evaluation on iris dataset but I am getting different results in Rstudio than in Python with rpy2. I have no idea why? anybody can please help me?

I tried to copy iris dataset from Rstudio to python but I am getting the same results - there is no mismatch in dataset. I am using python 2.7(Cloudera Anaconda implementation on server cluster) and rpy2==2.8.6.

pip install rpy2==2.8.6

## Python

from sklearn import datasets

from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri

from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

import pandas as pd

df_data = pd.DataFrame(iris.data[:150,:])

df_label= pd.DataFrame(iris.target[:150])

fpc = importr('fpc')

rdf_data =  pandas2ri.py2ri(df_data)

rdf_label = pandas2ri.py2ri(df_label)

cdbw = fpc.cdbw(rdf_data, rdf_label)

print(cdbw)

$cdbw
[1] 0.2586786

$cohesion
[1] 0.6164132

$compactness
[1] 0.6470029

$sep
[1] 0.6486081

## Rstudio

> iriss <- as.matrix(iris[c(1:150),-5])
>
> irisc <- as.numeric(iris[c(1:150),5])
>
> cdbw(iriss,irisc)

$cdbw
[1] 0.574

$cohesion
[1] 0.744

$compactness
[1] 0.787

$sep
[1] 0.98

Comment: I guess I resolved it, the labels have to start with 1 and not with 0(python), when I changed df_label to  df_label= pd.DataFrame(iris.target[:150]+1) i got the same result

Comment: what you experienced is the difference between zero and one indexing. R uses 1 indexed vectors, where most other software uses 0 indexing. Basically does the vector start at `vec[0]` og `vec[1]`. In practice it makes little difference. For future post please format your code sektions as code by marking code and clicking `ctrl+k`.